# Findstr: match filenames containing exactly a single dot

Tags: cmd.exe, findstr

I am desparately trying to find all files within a folder and its subdirectories containing exactly a single dot. Reading the documentation of findstr I came up with this kind-of-regex, but it still matches all file names containing dots.
In my understanding the regex I constructed should read: "Any characters except dots, then require a single dot, then again any characters except dots."

```
where /r directory *.* | findstr /irc:"[^\.]*\.[^\.]*"
```

I know I could install grep, but I want a solution that works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution myself.

As `[class]*` matches zero or more occurences this expression matched whenever there was at least one (as opposed to exactly one) dot within a filename.

To make it match exactly one the position of the dot has to be specified. In my case I simply added the position specifiers "^" (beginning of a line) and "$" (end of a line), so that now the regex translates to "Lines with exactly a single dot anywhere between beginning and end of the line"

```
where /r directory *.* | findstr /irc:"^[^\.]*\.[^\.]*$"
```